# Summernote not working properly on popup modal

Tags: jquery, browser, summernote

I am using summernote.js for html editor in bootrap modal popup. the Editable are in the editor not working by default. But it becoming working when when browser screen is resized or inspect element dev tool is opened . Any idea how to fix this

```
$(".summernote").summernote({
              height: 150,  
              toolbar: [
                    ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
                    ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
                    ['color', ['color']],
                    ['para', ['ul','ol','paragraph']],
                    ["view", ["fullscreen", "codeview"]]
                ],
            });

            $('i.note-recent-color').each(function(){
               $(this).attr('style','background-color: transparent;');
            });
```

And HTML code is

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade in" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog locationMail-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <input type="hidden" name="email-locationId" id="email-locationId" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="email-locationKey" id="email-locationKey" value="">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Email</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="modal-email">
                <label>To :     </label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="form-control" readonly>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-email">
                <label>Subject :    </label>
                <input type="text" name="emailsubject" id="emailsubject" value="" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-msg">
              <label>Message : </label>
              <textarea class="form-control summernote" name="emailcontent" id="emailcontent" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-cancel" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <img id="modal_loader" src="{{ env('APP_URL') }}/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif" style="display: none;">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-send" data-dismiss="modal">Send</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you please provide the HTML code as well?

Comment: please check the question now @RaviManiyar

Comment: Could you check my answer please? Let me know if it works. I have created a fiddle.

Comment: Yes, but now not working in  my case ,, i am using summernote-bs4.js

Comment: I've edited my fiddle to use summernot-bs4.js and it still works fine. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/q7khtspn/4/

Comment: Let me know if the fiddle has worked for you @user.

Comment: @RaviManiyar   the fiddle working, I have made some changes in css in this case, it is working now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a quick [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q7khtspn/) for you.

HTML:

```
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote.js"></script>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" id="mymodal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="summernote">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    jQuery(".summernote").summernote({
        height: 150,  
        toolbar: [
            ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
            ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
            ['color', ['color']],
            ['para', ['ul','ol','paragraph']],
            ["view", ["fullscreen", "codeview"]]
        ],
    });

    jQuery('i.note-recent-color').each(function(){
        jQuery(this).attr('style','background-color: transparent;');
    });
});
```